# how does lucene process dots ('.') in StringField? (issue indexing and searching file names)

Tags: lucene

I have a simple question I was not able to answer searching around or searching other questions: I am indexing a field which contains a filename with the following code:

doc.add(new TextField(FIELD_FILENAME, filename, Field.Store.YES))

if I index hello.jpg and then I search with the key 'hello.jpg' the entry is hit (so far so good). However, if I search with 'hello' I get no hits. If I replace '.' with another punctuation character while indexing then it works. If I escape the '.' it works as well (e.g. indexing "hello\.jpg" I find it searching for 'hello').

How Lucene process dots? Shall I expect the same issue with other characters?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on the analyzer you use, because the analyzer defines which tokenizer is used. The tokenizer is responsible for token extraction, which in the simplest case is similar to defining word boundaries.

Given the behavior you describe, I guess you're using the `StandardAnalyzer`, which uses the `StandardTokenizer`, which implements [Unicode text segmentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29), which states the following:

> For example, the period (U+002E <sub>FULL STOP</sub>) is used ambiguously, sometimes for end-of-sentence purposes, sometimes for abbreviations, and sometimes for numbers.

In the document, the full stop character is part of the [MidNumLet](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#MidNumLet) property value, and your specific case is handled by the WB6 and WB7 rules:

```
(ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) × (MidLetter | MidNumLet | Single_Quote) (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
(ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) (MidLetter | MidNumLet | Single_Quote) × (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
```

The `×` symbol means: *no word break allowed here*.

Put more simply: do not allow word breaks before or after a punctuation character if said character is immediately preceded **and** followed by a letter.

And the standard tokenizer grammar follows these rules:

```java
// UAX#29 WB5.   (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) × (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
//        WB6.   (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) × (MidLetter | MidNumLet | Single_Quote) (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
//        WB7.   (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) (MidLetter | MidNumLet | Single_Quote) × (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
//        WB7a.  Hebrew_Letter × Single_Quote
//        WB7b.  Hebrew_Letter × Double_Quote Hebrew_Letter
//        WB7c.  Hebrew_Letter Double_Quote × Hebrew_Letter
//        WB9.   (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter) × Numeric
//        WB10.  Numeric × (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter)
//        WB13.  Katakana × Katakana
//        WB13a. (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter | Numeric | Katakana | ExtendNumLet) × ExtendNumLet
//        WB13b. ExtendNumLet × (ALetter | Hebrew_Letter | Numeric | Katakana) 
//
{ExtendNumLetEx}*  ( {KatakanaEx}          ( {ExtendNumLetEx}*   {KatakanaEx}                           )*
                   | ( {HebrewLetterEx}    ( {SingleQuoteEx}     | {DoubleQuoteEx}  {HebrewLetterEx}    )
                     | {NumericEx}         ( ( {ExtendNumLetEx}* | {MidNumericEx} ) {NumericEx}         )*
                     | {HebrewOrALetterEx} ( ( {ExtendNumLetEx}* | {MidLetterEx}  ) {HebrewOrALetterEx} )*
                     )+
                   )
({ExtendNumLetEx}+ ( {KatakanaEx}          ( {ExtendNumLetEx}*   {KatakanaEx}                           )*
                   | ( {HebrewLetterEx}    ( {SingleQuoteEx}     | {DoubleQuoteEx}  {HebrewLetterEx}    )
                     | {NumericEx}         ( ( {ExtendNumLetEx}* | {MidNumericEx} ) {NumericEx}         )*
                     | {HebrewOrALetterEx} ( ( {ExtendNumLetEx}* | {MidLetterEx}  ) {HebrewOrALetterEx} )*
                     )+
                   )
)*
{ExtendNumLetEx}* 
  { return WORD_TYPE; }
```

In conclusion:
If you need a different behavior, you have to use a different analyzer that will better suit your goal. I guess something like [LetterTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LetterTokenizer.html) wouldn't suit but you may create your own tokenizer based on [CharTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/CharTokenizer.html) to implement your own rules.

Comment: Thanks. Your reply lead me toward the online demo https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/breaks.jsp which was mostly helpful when debugging similar issue.