# Azure Search doesnt work when searching by text using dot as a second last character in a wild card search

Tags: c#, azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

IN Azure search when searching for a name within the index record if you end up putting a dot at the end of the search term, the search logic cannot find the item even if it exists. (Please note we are appending wildcard at the end of all search term.)

For e.g. if we have a indexed record with a name companyltd. and we run a query as shown below

```
        _index.Documents.SearchAsync<testDto>("companyltd*", new SearchParameters());
```

This returns the record with a name companyltd.

However if we run the query

```
       _index.Documents.SearchAsync<testDto>("companyltd.*", new SearchParameters());
```

It cannot find the record with the name companyltd.

Could someone please explain why this is the case and what should the search query be like to get the result back as expected?

Comment: The char '.' is considered a stop word. If probably does not exists in your index. For the second query, are is the idea for the '*'? Do you want to search for words that start with companyltd. ?

Comment: Thats right @ThiagoCustodio . We want to search for words that start with companyltd.

Comment: Also the record we are looking for definately exists in the index.

Comment: Trust me, it's removing the '.' in the index because it's considered a stopword.(read in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#property-reference). You can solve it using regular expression and pass /companyltd.*/ , escape dots when indexing or provide a suggester (auto complete feature with items that exists in your index)

Comment: Thank you @ThiagoCustodio  . I checked the index records and i can clearly see the index record with the name "companyItd." I am trying to escape the dot in the search query  as you suggested and i know it will work but cannot get the syntax to do so, Do you know the syntax to escape the dot?

Comment: you must understand how a search engine works. One thing is your content another is how and what is stored in the inverted index (words)

Comment: Here are a good resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450031/1384539 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture In summary, you'll need to use a different analyzer, or work on the other options I gave. (suggester, regex)

Comment: Thanks  @ThiagoCustodio. Really appreciate your help. Just for your the record, when i use fuzzy search i.e ~ instead of * it works. i'll look into those resources as well.